# VIM: insert empty ERB tags

Tags: vim, tags, erb, surround

How can I insert empty ERB tags and put cursor inside it? It is similar to surrounding with surround plugin, but there is nothing to surround.

For example, from this:

```
bla|bla
```

I want get this:

```
bla<%= | %>bla
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use Tim Pope's surround plugin to accomplish this.

Add the following to you ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/erb.vim

```
let b:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= \r %>"
let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>"
```

Now when you press `<c-s>=` it will insert `<%= | %>` just as you wanted.

You may also want to look at Tim Pope's [ragtag plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896) which has such mappings already included.

Comment: What does it mean: <c-s>=? Is it 'change selection' shortcut (cs)? I have tried that commands, but them do work only if there is some text selected.

Answer (score 1):

To insert predefined block of text, you should have a look at [Snipmate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php%3Fscript_id%3D2540). It will insert code and position the cursor to a predefined position.

I am not sure ERB is supported but it is very easy to add your own snippets.

For example, something like :

```
snippet ta
     <%= ${1} %>
```

in erb.snippets should insert the text when typing `ta`

However, you can find plenty of snippets for Snipmate online.

For example, https://github.com/scrooloose/snipmate-snippets contains lots of predefined snippets.

See [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658737/vim-html-erb-snippets-snipmate-need-a-vim-tip/4658863#4658863) on how to install them.