# Adding erb wrap to surround.vim

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim, erb

I am attempting to edit my surround.vim file, to map a quick key for adding erb tags. Here is the stackoverflow post I am referring to:

[VIM: insert empty ERB tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117991/vim-insert-empty-erb-tags).

I am using this VIM Package https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim, which includes Surround.vim

The answer on that stackoverflow post says there is a file located at "~/.vim/after/ftplugin/erb.vim"

Since I am using the bundle my file structure is different, I dug through and was able to find this 
"~/.vim/bundle/vim-surround/plugin/surround.vim"

That file shows the following portion of code: (the full code is on a gist here https://gist.github.com/lando2319/5650746 )

```
  elseif exists("b:surround_".char2nr(newchar))
    let all    = s:process(b:surround_{char2nr(newchar)})
    let before = s:extractbefore(all)
    let after  =  s:extractafter(all)
  elseif exists("g:surround_".char2nr(newchar))
    let all    = s:process(g:surround_{char2nr(newchar)})
    let before = s:extractbefore(all)
    let after  =  s:extractafter(all)
  elseif newchar ==# "p"
    let before = "\n"
    let after  = "\n\n"
  elseif newchar ==# 's'
    let before = ' '
    let after  = ''
  elseif newchar ==# ':'
    let before = ':'
    let after = ''
```

If I am understanding this correctly I need to add the code below to this file somewhere to my surround.vim file, I believe somewhere around line 151.

```
let b:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= \r %>"
let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>"
```

So far I tried adding it to a few places then closing and reopening a file in VIM, then "cntl-s, =" so far no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any plugin that requires you to insert some of your own code in it is a bad plugin. I think any customization you need to make to surround.vim should happen in your `vimrc` file.

Comment: ok good to know, I opened my .vimrc file and I see:

I tried to add it but nothing seems to be happening

Comment: By the way, drop SPF13. It feels good at first but it will only slow your learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/erb.vim` and add the following lines:

```
let b:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= \r %>"
let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>"
```

The other method is to use `autocmd`'s to activate the surround mappings. I tend prefer using `~/.vim/after/` directory instead of cluttering up my `~/.vimrc` with filetype specific settings.

Comment: This required me to create the folder ftplugin and the file erb.vim, in any event I did so restarted my terminal, opened a new file in vim hit "Ctrl-s, -" and nothing happens.

Comment: The magic word here is terminal. `<c-s>` will activate flow control on most terminals. You should instead use the alternative mapping of `<c-g>s`. So `<c-g>s=` in your case. Open up your erb file and try it out. To verify if the surrounding variables are set use the following: `:echo exists('b:surround_61')`. This should return 1 if the `=` surrounding variable is set correctly. Note: `char2nr('=')` is 61.

Comment: WORKS <c-g>s- and <c-g>s= (or ctrl-g,s,- and ctrl-g,s,=) that was what I was looking for thank you. This has been a big VIM learning experience.

Answer (score 2):

No you should not add the two lines into the plugin's (surround.vim) source. You should add them into your vimrc.

If you want your `- and =` does `<% \r %>` and `<%= \r %>` for all filetypes  when you do surrounding, (e.g. `yss-` or `yss=`) .

You just add

```
let g:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= \r %>"
let g:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>"
```

to your vimrc. please notice that they are global (with `g:` prefix) variables.

If you just want your customized `- and =` to work for certain filetype,  you could create an `autocmd` and set buffer scope variables (with `b:`, same as the two lines in your question)

I am not familiar with ruby world. assume that the filetype you want to use the surrounding is `erb`, you could in your vimrc:

```
fun! AutoCmd_ERB()
        "do some other settings/mappings for your ERB, if you have
        "......
        "the customized surrounding :
        let b:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= \r %>"
        let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>"
endf
autocmd FileType erb call AutoCmd_ERB()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Here is the .vimrc file I am starting with https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim/blob/3.0/.vimrc

I added your code to line 306 but nothing seemed to happen, do I need to restart something or is this suppost to take effect right away?, With this code I should be about to use "Ctrl-s, =" correct? not sure why its not working.

Comment: either re-source your vimrc file or close and start vim. `ctrl-s` in insert mode is an experimental feature, I don't use it, since I mostly work on terminal. you could just open one erb file and on any line, press `yss-` (Normal mode) to see what happened.

Comment: `<c-g>s` will activate insert mode surrounding in the terminal. I prefer to disable flow control via: `stty -ixon` in my `~/.bashrc` file. This allows me to use `<c-s>`.

Comment: `yss` operates on the current line. Try `ys` followed a motion. Like `ys$-` or `ysiw-`. Please read the surround documentation via `:h surround`

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Vim, I suppose!

Never edit plugin source files, it is always wrong.

Whenever you need to customize your setup, your vimrc file is where it happens. Type [`:h vimrc-intro`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#vimrc-intro) to learn more.

In the case of *surround.vim*, the documentation states

> The following adds a potential replacement on "-" (ASCII 45) in PHP files. (...) The carriage return will be replaced by the original text.
>
> ```
> autocmd FileType php let b:surround_45 = "<?php \r ?>"
> ```

This means that you need to add the following entries to your vimrc file. For your purposes, this means that you need to add the lines

```
autocmd FileType erb let b:surround_{char2nr('=')} = "<%= \r %>"
autocmd FileType erb let b:surround_{char2nr('-')} = "<% \r %>"
```

to your vimrc file. Your vimrc file is located at `~/.vimrc` (or `$HOME\_vimrc` if you're on Windows).

Restart Vim and you're ready to get to work.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone, for me it worked after i changed the name from "erb.vim" to "eruby.vim" in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin.