# How to add <%= %> & variants in vim insert mode while using vim-rails and vim-surround?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

Is there any vim mapping/plugin that produces the following behaviour in an .erb file while having [vim-rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) and [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) installed?

mapping/key-press [*normal mode*]
`<%= *cursor position* %>` [*insert mode*]

Same with `<% %>` and `<%# %>`.

Note: I know I can just surround it with [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) after writing it. I want to know the reverse way.
That way I get syntax highlighting while writing the inner ruby code.

Comment: do you just want to wrap your cursor? or some certain text?

Comment: I have found similar posts: [VIM: insert empty ERB tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5117991/438329) and [Using VIM effectively with Ruby/Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17222197/438329)

Comment: Thank you Peter. The answer that worked for me is an actual mix of both of your suggestions. You see, I already had vim-rails and vim-surround installed. The problem is that the <C-s>= in insertmode wasn't working. Turns out you need to do <C-g>s= to get it to work on a terminal.Why is that?

Re: dup-question 1, it doesn't quite answer my question, since I don't add custom commands in other files that aren't my vimrc. That way I can version control it better.

Re: dup-question 2, the answer to that question doesn't answer this one, under my parameters.

I will edit this question now.

Comment: Should I answer the question myself? Dupes above (while related) do not answer my particular question with edited scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [RagTag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1896) or [Rails](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) plugins (in addition to surround) which provides the surroundings you need. You would use Rails.vim if you are using rails and RagTag otherwise. You can have both installed if needed.

Once you have surround and RagTag/Rails installed you can just do the following:

- `<c-s>=` insert mode for `<%= %>`
- `<c-s>#` insert mode for `<%# %>`
- Visually select code and do `S=` to surround with `<%=` and `%>`

Note: You may have to use `<c-g>s` for insert mode surrounding if you are using a the terminal. You could also disable your terminal flow control by running `stty -ixon` which would allow you to use the `<c-s>`/`<c-q>` keys (I personally disable flow control in my `~/.bashrc`).

If you want to add "surroundings" to other filetypes please read `:h surround-customizing`.

Please read both the surround documentation and whichever plugin you decide to install for more details.

Comment: If you edit the question to remove the let b:surround bit (since it's not needed), and add a note to account for different terminal mappings (`<C-g>g=` in this case) I will mark it as answered, since that is the actual answer to my question. Suggestions above do not work as an answer to my question.

Comment: I have edit the post to mention terminal support